# available disk space

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, disk-usage

according to my provider I have two disks with 250G space on my linux server

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME    FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sdb                       238.5G
├─sdb2  linux_raid_member   512M            rescue:1
│ └─md1 ext3              511.4M /boot
├─sdb3  linux_raid_member   222G            rescue:2
│ └─md2 ext4              221.9G /
└─sdb1  linux_raid_member    16G            rescue:0
└─md0 swap                 16G [SWAP]
sda                       238.5G
├─sda2  linux_raid_member   512M            rescue:1
│ └─md1 ext3              511.4M /boot
├─sda3  linux_raid_member   222G            rescue:2
│ └─md2 ext4              221.9G /
└─sda1  linux_raid_member    16G            rescue:0
└─md0 swap                 16G [SWAP]

root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  318M  2.9G  10% /run
/dev/md2        219G  208G     0 100% /
tmpfs            16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           8.0G  1.4G  6.7G  17% /opt/zammad/tmp
/dev/md1        488M  199M  264M  43% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

I deleted some backups (more than 21GB) in `/opt/zammad-db-backups`

then I got

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /opt/zammad-db-backups # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  318M  2.9G  10% /run
/dev/md2        219G  207G  715M 100% /
tmpfs            16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           8.0G  1.4G  6.7G  17% /opt/zammad/tmp
/dev/md1        488M  199M  264M  43% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

Why I got only 715M in '/'? where is the rest of the >21GB?

and why do I get only

```
du / -sh
du: cannot access '/proc/21051/task/21051/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/21051/task/21051/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/21051/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/21051/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
85G     /
```

85G used when the df command tells me root mount point I have 100% of 219G used

Is the raid system using the rest to provide redundant data? 250GB Disk and I can roughly use 85 GB (plus the rest of partitions ok but still it's to much (?))

Output of df -i

```
df -i
Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            4092629     461  4092168    1% /dev
tmpfs           4099946    1691  4098255    1% /run
/dev/md2       14540800 3453478 11087322   24% /
tmpfs           4099946       2  4099944    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4099946       4  4099942    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4099946      17  4099929    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           4099946  334275  3765671    9% /opt/zammad/tmp
/dev/md1         131072     308   130764    1% /boot
tmpfs           4099946       4  4099942    1% /run/user/0
```

Comment: No, you have a 219G filesystem (backed by partitions on 2 RAID disks). You can have space held by files that have been erased but still open. Did you reboot (best way to restart everything). What is the output of `df -i`?

Comment: @xenoid I updated the question with the output of `df-i` No I haven't reboot but I will do it now.

Comment: @xenoid you are right after rebooting I have `/dev/md2        219G   98G  110G  48% /`   very confusing. Thank you

Comment: If you delete a file that is open by a program, the data on disk will be deleted only when the file is closed. The same if there are more hard links to the same file on disk, the data will be deleted only when the last hard link is deleted. Both hard links and open's are counted, and first when the count is zero the data is deleted physically from disk.

Comment: Thank you also @SorenA it seem to me then I have a bigger problem on the server I mean 110G blocked this way well does any one know how I can find this died processes with open files?

Comment: An eventual process holding files open will disappear when rebooting.

Comment: @SorenA yes I know. I meant before rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have a partition of some size then formatting it might a) drop some non-useable fractions at the end of the partition due to the granularity of the file system, and b) use up some space for managing the data this new volume including the journaling (crash fail safe feature) and similar things (like wear reduction methods). this is natural and specific to the selected file system. selecting (or designing) a different file system can change this. sometimes there are configuration options to the file system at creation time that can alter this memory consumption footprint as well. some file systems might even be able to re-configure an existing volume.

when your system is running you might have running applications that have used up some space, released it again but have not yet closed those files (via their file handles). there might be further aspects in this scope, e.g. the special case handling for hard-links. closing applications selectively might free and thus unveil the originator. just cleaning up the state should happen when the machine is rebooted next time. there should be tools for monitoring file handles and file usage of applications - e.g. the 'strace' tool shows some basic capabilities. (there are some more advanced approaches out there for such sort of monitoring, some of them are still based on the stock 'strace' binary.) just monitoring the list-able files in the system is probably less likely to unveil the root cause for those specific case.

Comment: Can I find those files and the processes with something like `lsof`?

Comment: it depends. how about solving that in a separate question? (some cross references to this topic should be okay.)